# Imacros extracting urls

Tags: vbscript, imacros

This script is meant to Loop through Youtube videos collecting their URLs.

```
Option Explicit

'initiate iMacros instance
Dim iim1, iret
set iim1 = CreateObject ("imacros")
iret = iim1.iimInit()

'navigate to youtube frontpage
Dim macro
macro = "CODE:"
macro = macro + "VERSION BUILD=7601105     " + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "TAB T=1     " + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS     " + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "URL GOTO=http://www.youtube.com/     " + vbNewLine

iret = iim1.iimPlay(macro)

'loop through videos
Dim counter
counter = 0
do while not iret < 0
   counter = counter + 1
   macro = "CODE:"
   macro = macro + "TAG POS=R"+Cstr(counter)+" TYPE=IMG ATTR=CLASS:vimg120&&TITLE:*&&HREF:*&&NAME:*&&ALT:video&&SRC:*   " + vbNewLine
   macro = macro + "PROMPT Current<SP>URL:<SP>{{!URLCURRENT}}" + vbNewLine
   macro = macro + "BACK"
   iret = iim1.iimPlay(macro)
loop


'end
msgbox "End. We'll close the iMacros browser and exit the VBS script."

'close iMacros instance
iret = iim1.iimExit()

' exit script
Wscript.Quit(
```

For some reason It doesn't seem to work.
It returns this : SyntaxError: unknown command: OPTION, line: 1 (Error code: -910)
Please help me out.
Thanks.

Edit: Looks like I figured it out this script must be run as a VBS script(File.vbs for example) and not direct within the Imacros browser.

But I still have a problem.
This script is meant to save the URLs extracted in the above script:

```
    SET !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=myFolder FILE=myFile.csv
```

Where shall I insert this exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and let me know if it works. I didn't do VBS so far but this could work.

```
Option Explicit

'initiate iMacros instance
Dim iim1, iret
set iim1 = CreateObject ("imacros")
iret = iim1.iimInit()

'navigate to youtube frontpage
Dim macro
macro = "CODE:"
macro = macro + "VERSION BUILD=7601105     " + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "TAB T=1     " + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS     " + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "URL GOTO=http://www.youtube.com/     " + vbNewLine

iret = iim1.iimPlay(macro)

'loop through videos
Dim counter
counter = 0
do while not iret < 0
   counter = counter + 1
   macro = "CODE:"
   macro = macro + "TAG POS=R"+Cstr(counter)+" TYPE=IMG ATTR=CLASS:vimg120&&TITLE:*&&HREF:*&&NAME:*&&ALT:video&&SRC:*   " + vbNewLine
   macro = macro + "PROMPT Current<SP>URL:<SP>{{!URLCURRENT}}" + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "SET !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}" + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=myFolder FILE=myFile.csv" + vbNewLine
   macro = macro + "BACK"
   iret = iim1.iimPlay(macro)
loop


'end
msgbox "End. We'll close the iMacros browser and exit the VBS script."

'close iMacros instance
iret = iim1.iimExit()

' exit script
Wscript.Quit()
```

Comment: Hey IceD,
Thanks for replying.

It returns this error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'imacros'
Line:5
Char:1
I'm using Imacros for firefox not the full Imacros version if that helps.

Comment: I donn't know how to help you on this one since I do not do VB but this can help you. http://wiki.imacros.net/Main_Page